# What are technical requirements in order to make "Recommend This Site" button work properly

Tags: facebook, iframe, meta, app-id

I am getting odd and inconsistent "Like" counter results on my site.

Do I need a `FB App Id`?

Do I need to have this meta tag present on the page?

```
<meta content="123456789012345" property="fb:app_id" />
```

Do I need a FB App Id parameter on my iframe tag?

```
?app_id=123456789012345
```

Is this iframe tag coded properly (indentation for readability only)?

```
<iframe
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php
        ?app_id=123456789012345
        &amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2F
        &amp;layout=standard
        &amp;show_faces=false
        &amp;width=170
        &amp;action=like
        &amp;font
        &amp;colorscheme=light
        &amp;height=30"
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:170px; height:30px;"
    allowTransparency="true"
>
</iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your iframe code, atleast according to the auto-generate feature at [Facebook Like Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Iframe like buttons can't include the Send button, for which their Javascript sdk is required, for this the auto generated code has a parameter `&amp;send=false`, which is missing in your code.

If you are using the app_id, then again according to the auto gen code the order of parameters is incorrect, although **i'm not sure** if that could be a problem. Best way is to stick to the auto gen code and modify accordingly.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
&amp;send=false
&amp;layout=standard
&amp;width=450
&amp;show_faces=true
&amp;action=like
&amp;colorscheme=light
&amp;font
&amp;height=80
&amp;appId=123123123123123" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

You do not need the app id absolutely(so you can remove the last parameter), but if you use the javscript sdk you need it. For the meta tags you can use your own fb id instead of app id.

It is again best to use the meta tags as **generated** in the docs from the above link. I would also recommend you to use the meta tags correctly, because that allows the facebook scraper/crawler to get proper info from your site, and display likes on news feeds correctly, with more information.

So just auto-generate your code from the link, and you are good to go. Also go through the documentation.

Comment: ask for clarifications if required.

Comment: Thanks @bool.dev. I will re-generate the code from the "auto-generate" script page. I did it in the beginning, but I might have over-tweaked the iframe tag settings since. I will also page through the doc as well.

Comment: You (@bool.dev) stated "You do not need the app id absolutely(so you can remove the last parameter), but if you use the javscript sdk you need it." Can you clarify your comment "but if you use the javscript sdk"? Am I using the "sdk" by using my code? Thanks.

Comment: from the code you have given, it doesn't seem like you are using the(facebook's) javascript sdk. But if you are using their plugins, like requests/invites or login button etc, then you might be using the javascript sdk. Basically if you have, somewhere in your code, this line : `FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });` it means..

Comment: ..that you are using it. You can read the documentation for that at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ . And p.s-thanks for the upvote

Comment: Ok, thanks @bool.dev. I know, based on your explanation, that I am _not_ using the SDK.

Comment: at @bool.dev - I am using this generator `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/`

Comment: Rebuilt my iframe code structure. Removed my app id meta tag. Will monitor behavior for a week or so.

Comment: everything that you have done now, seems ok, but just keep an eye out, (incase things don't work out) on this bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/313973271956387/?browse=search_4ef99fcfc85fe1027824779 , however, i can guarantee that if you have the code generated, and also the meta tags correctly, then there won't be any problem, and 1 week time is enough for verifying that. the crawlers take atleast 24 hrs before visiting your url.

Comment: following up, are you getting expected behavior now?